# Different types of smooth object movement

Tags: math

In a game I have a specific object and two positions the object will move from and to.
I already have the function for calculating current position in specific time.

It works like this:

Inputting 0 will move the object to Position 1.

Inputting 1 will move the object to Position 2.

Inputting 0.5 will move the object in the middle of the two positions.

etc...

(In the examples below, time is varying from 0 to 1)
When I want to start the object slowly and stop it when it is moving fast, I use:

```
MoveObject(sin(time * 90))
```

When I want to start the object fast and stop it as it is getting slower, I use:

```
MoveObject(1 - cos(time * 90))
```

Without the effects, it's:

```
MoveObject(time)
```

How do I make the object start moving slowly, move fast in the center of two positions and then get slower while reaching the second position?

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
MoveObject((time) * (time) * (3 - 2 * (time)))
```

[sol.gfxile.net/interpolation](http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation)

Comment: `3*(t^2) - 2*(t^3)` is called an **ease curve** (for future reference)